# Sequelize creates two (unexpected) foreign keys when doing hasMany association

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I encountered an issue while working on a database to manage stores. I wanted to create a one-to-many association between stores and users, where each store has a user as its owner.
However, when I set the associations **it creates two foreign keys in the stores table** (ownerId and userId).

I used this [example in the sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#multiple-associations-involving-the-same-models) as a reference and defined the associations as follows:

./models/index.js

```js
const User = require('./user.model');
const Store = require('./store.model');

Store.belongsTo(User, { as: 'owner' });
User.hasMany(Store);

module.exports = { User, Store };
```

I solved this issue by specifying "ownerId" as the foreign key in the User model, like this:
`User.hasMany(Store, { foreignKey: 'ownerId' });`

I'm wondering why this happens and if this is the best solution. Shouldn't Sequelize automatically detect that the foreign key is ownerId?

I'm using sequelize v6.31.1 with PostgreSQL 15.
These are my models:

user.model.js

```js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db.config');


const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  role: {
    type: DataTypes.ENUM('admin', 'owner', 'customer'),
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: 'customer'
  }
});

module.exports = User;
```

store.model.js

```js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db.config');


const Store = sequelize.define('store', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
  description: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true
  },
  address: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true
  }
});


module.exports = Store;
```

Thank you all for your comments and insights! They are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequelize can't guess that you want `ownerId` in **both** relationships because the association where you indicated `as: owner` now has a customized foreign key generated using the alias name.
You either don't use aliases in such paired associations or indicate the same `foreignKey` option and its value so that Sequelize knows it's the same thing.

```js
Store.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(Store);
```

or

```js
Store.belongsTo(User, { as: 'owner', foreignKey: 'ownerId' });
User.hasMany(Store, { foreignKey: 'ownerId' });
```

Sequelize does not assume that these two associations are linked to each other because you could have several associations between the same tables (in this case you need to use explicit aliases to distinguish associations):

```js
Store.belongsTo(User, { as: 'owner', foreignKey: 'ownerId' });
Store.belongsTo(User, { as: 'manager', foreignKey: 'managerId' });
User.hasMany(Store, { foreignKey: 'ownerId', as: 'ownedStores' });
User.hasMany(Store, { foreignKey: 'managerId', as: 'managingStores' });
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! Now I understand clearly why this was happening, and I'm relieved that the implemented solution is the most appropriate one. With your example, I understand it much better.Thank you very much Anatoly for sharing your knowledge! Best regards!